# When returning a constant value from a pl/sql function which way is better?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am working on an existing package and i found a function like this;

```
   FUNCTION get_lang
      RETURN VARCHAR2
   AS
      l_ret_lang   VARCHAR2 (10);
   BEGIN
      SELECT 'US' LANGUAGE
        INTO l_ret_lang
        FROM DUAL;

      RETURN l_ret_lang;
   EXCEPTION
      WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
      THEN
         l_ret_lang := ' ';
         RETURN l_ret_lang;
      WHEN OTHERS
      THEN
         l_ret_lang := SUBSTR (SQLERRM, 1, 100);
         RETURN l_ret_lang;
   END;
```

Is there any logical reason to define a function like this,
isnt it better to define more simple version like below?

```
  FUNCTION get_lang
  RETURN VARCHAR2
   AS
      l_ret_lang   VARCHAR2 (10):= 'US';
   BEGIN

      RETURN l_ret_lang;

   END;
```

Also select from dual expression can raise an exception?

Comment: A function: `function get_lang return varchar2 is begin return 'US'; end;` or a (package) constant: `g_lang constant varchar2(2) := 'US';`

Comment: Wow, that function is really moronic for a number of reasons. Not just the pointless query, but also using the magic value `' '` and returning a chunk of an error message if anything unexpected occurs.

Comment: I suggest you define the body of the function as `RETURN 'US';`. `'US'` is a constant - IMO there's no reason to create and initialize a variable to hold this value just so it can be returned. As far as 'Can a SELECT from DUAL raise an exception' - although I'm sure there are ways for a `SELECT FROM DUAL` to fail such a failure means that the database is very badly compromised and there will doubtless be other problems occurring in rapid order. Putting in an exception handler in this case is pointless, in my opinion. Share and enjoy.

Comment: Thanks for the answers and comments, changed the structure to simple function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> "Also select from dual expression can raise an exception?"

DUAL is a system table, used for all sorts of operations, and nobody should ever touch it.  If `select` anything from DUAL fails you've got big problems.  Probably you'll have failures all over the system.

So I would say, in this case the function is definitely over-engineered and the lightweight second function is the better approach.

More generally, is this the best way to handle constants?  It depends on the scenario,  In some cases, hard-coding a value in a PL/SQL function is enough.  Other systems may benefit from a lookup table and a generic, parameterized function.

Partly it depends on usage.  If the constant value is required mainly in other PL/SQL code I would be inclined to replace the function call with a straightforward PL/SQL CONSTANT declaration, perhaps in a package spec of constants.  In this situation if there was a need to reference the constant in queries  I would write a function like this:

```
create or replace package constants as
    g_lang constant varchar2(2) := 'US';
    function get_lang return varchar2;
end constants;
/
create or replace package body constants as
    function get_lang return varchar2
    is
    begin
        return g_lang;
    end get_lang;
end constants;
/
```

Comment: Would you declare the function as DETERMINISTIC?

Comment: If I was writing this as enterprise software rather than a toy example on SO?  Yes.

Answer (score 0):

There's no good reason to use `dual` for a simple function that just returns a constant. The fact that someone wrote it doesn't necessarily that they knew what they were doing, or, on a more positive note, that the design considerations that existed X years ago when the function was written still apply today.

Answer (score 0):

For returning a simple constant, the select from dual is way overengineered. Avoid it.

I really don't see the point of wrapping this in a function at all. It is really a package constant. If it is a constant you call a lot, or from SQL, it might be an excuse to play around with Oracle's INLINE feature for PL/SQL functins.

```
PRAGMA INLINE(get_lang,'YES');
country := get_lang();
```

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/inline_pragma.htm

http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=502

I only wish it was an option that could be set on the function itself, rather than the call site. I imagine in the future it will be.

Comment: Can you inline a separately compiled function?

Comment: Will inline functionality make any performance improvment for this kind of simple function?

Comment: Inlining isn't about the simplicity of the function, it is about the frequency and latency of any function call. For example, if you had a function in a loop, or inside another highly called function. As for this function, no, I see no reason to inline it, but I also see no reason to make it a function in the first place. It really should be a package constant (IMO).